# ant's replaceregexp , to remove a specific space

Tags: regex, ant

I can't find the way to remove a space using ant. (I don't mean trim, but removing from ~ to )

I want to make one project a little difference from another project.

For example:

I have below code.

```
.... doSomeThing;

//#removeStart

NotReleasedObject nro = new NotReleasedObject();
nro.doSomeThing();

//removeEnd#

....doAnyThing..
```

as you can see easily, I want to remove from `//#removeStart` to `//removeEnd#`. I'm not sure how much code will be written, but all code inside these 2 tags need to be gone.And there can be multiple `//#removeStart ... //removeEnd#` in one java file.

Here is my test `replaceregexp` code:

```
<replaceregexp flags="s" replace="" byline="false" encoding="utf-8">
        <regexp pattern="//#removeStart.*//removeEnd#"/>
        <fileset dir="${extern-source-path}"/>
</replaceregexp>

------ source for victim.

//#removeStart
space 1
//removeEnd#

something

//#removeStart
space 2
//removeEnd#
```

Now my code is not working properly.The flag -s works, but if one file has more than 1  match, then everything from space 1 to space 2 is gone. ( including `something`!)
What I actually want is space 1,2 gone, but `something` should be left as it is.

How can I fix it so that it replaces each occurrence 1 by 1 ?

Comment: no worries .. you were still able to convey the message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your explicit characters don't match: your regex says `//##ExternRemove` whereas your actual text is either `//##removeStart` or `//#removeStart`. If that's an actual regex, the explicit characters need to be exactly the same.  Also `.` doesn't match newlines, you'd need to include that specifically (e.g. `[\s\S]*`).

Finally, you should make the matching non-greedy if you might have multiple pairs of this match (often this is by adding `?`). Taken together, you'd probably want a regular expression like:

```
//##?removeStart[\s\S]*?//removeEnd##?
```

That's assuming you want to allow 1-2 `#` to start a line and that the phrase will always be `removeStart`/`removeEnd`. Otherwise you could add options, e.g.

```
//##?(?:removeStart|ExternRemove)[\s\S]*?//(?:removeEnd|ExternEnd)##?
```

again, this depends on the ant terminology for non-capturing matches.

Comment: great!!! the token '?' is what I really wanted to know! now It worked correctly. and, the token miss match between externRemove and removeStart is my mistake for paste. anyway, thank you!

Comment: I checked a button. is this accecpt your answer ? :D

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully did it with this:

#### foo.txt

```
This is a test
--->
###start remove
Blah blah blah
Yadda yadda yadda
###end remove
--->
End of my test
```

#### build.xml

```
<project>
    <replaceregexp file="foo.txt"
        flags="s"
        match="###start remove.+###end remove"
        replace=""/>
</project>
```

#### Resulting foo.txt

```
This is a test
--->

--->
End of my test
```

It looks like your *regex* are not quite right. You're *regex* is saying `##ExternRemove.*`, but your file has `//#removeStart` instead.

I was seeing if I could do this in a copy or concat, because I hate changing files directly. Unfortunately, I hadn't figured out a way to do this.

Comment: have you tested with more than 1 occurrence of the string in a file ?

Comment: thanx your reply! and, I worked with your source, but It actually has same problem with I mention. ( look my last sentence in question. and Jeff's source was done successfully :D ) and the token miss match between externRemove and removeStart is my mistake for paste. anyway, thank you!